# Ideal generated by linearly independent irreducible polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are linearly independent irreducible polynomials of degree $d$ and $e$ respectively in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ and let $I = (f,g)$ be the ideal generated by $f$ and $g$. What is the quotient ring $\mathbb{C}[x,y] / I$ like? I think I should argue with the degree $d$ and $e$ but having trouble setting up the cases. I'm new to the subject, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Thinking about questions like this is one way to get drawn into algebraic geometry. A comprehensive answer woud fill up a book, or at least a chapter. Anyway, we can think of $R_1=\Bbb{C}[x,y]/(f)$ telling us something about the set of zeros $V(f)$ of $f$ in $\Bbb{C}^2$. Basically because polynomial functions on $V(f)$ are more or less the elements of $R_1$. Similarly with the zero set of $V(g)$ and $R_2=\Bbb{C}[x,y]/(g)$. Your ring emerges when we look at the common zeros of $f$ and $g$. As $f$ and $g$ are linearly independent and irreducible, these are finite in number.

Comment: (cont'd) But the "type of contact" the two zero sets have at an intersection also shows. As starting examples consider the pairs 1) $f(x,y)=x$, $g(x,y)=y$, 2) $f(x,y)=y$, $g(x,y)=x^2-1-y$, 3) $f(x,y)=y$, $g(x,y)=x^2-y$, 4) $f(x,y)=x^2-y$, $g(x,y)=x^2+y^2-2$, 5) $f(x,y)=(x-1)^2+y^2-1$, $g(x,y)=(x+1)^2+y^2-1$. You may see how the number of common zeros shows in the dimension of $R$. Whether there is tangency or a usual intersection also plays a role.